# Generate enums at compiletime in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum `Color`, which has about 40 colors: `BLACK`, `WHITE`, `RED`, etc.

I have a second enum `ColorListPreset`, which contains a bunch of collections of `Color`s, such as `PRIMARY`, `SECONDARY`, `ALL`, `ONLY_WHITE`, `NOT_WHITE`. My question concerns these last two entries.

For each `Color`, I want `ColorListPreset` to contain an `ONLY_` entry (collection of size 1) and a `NOT_` entry (collection of size n-1, e.g. all `Color`s except `WHITE`). We only have a couple `NOT_` entries in use today, but would like to have one per `Color`.

Currently, these collections are curated by hand, but ideally these two types would be autogenerated from the `Color` enum while still being accessible via `ColorListPreset.NOT_WHITE` in a way that my IDE will recognize.

For the sake of argument, say that accessing these values via member access (e.g. `ColorListPreset.NOT_WHITE`) is more important than the effort that goes into maintaining the collections.

Is there a way to accomplish this? A pure-Java solution is ideal. Solutions that change the type of `ColorListPreset` are welcome, so long as member access is maintained.

The best idea I've come up with (though I haven't yet attempted implementing) is to list out the `ONLY_` and `NOT_` enums in name only, then generate their collections in the constructor via `this.name()` and `Color.values()`. I don't have a concept where even the enum names are generated.

---

Current code samples:

```java
public enum Color {
    BLACK("black", "0x000000"),
    GRAY("gray", "0x7f7f7f"),
    WHITE("white", "0xffffff"),
    RED("red", "0xff0000"),
    GREEN("green", "0x00ff00"),
    BLUE("blue", "0x0000ff");
    // and so on...
}
```

```java
public enum ColorListPreset {
    NONE(Util.arrayListOf()),
    ALL(Util.arrayListOf(Color.BLACK, Color.GRAY, Color.WHITE, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE)),
    GRAYSCALE(Util.arrayListOf(Color.BLACK, Color.GRAY, Color.WHITE)),
    PRIMARY(Util.arrayListOf(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE)),

    ONLY_WHITE(Util.arrayListOf(Color.WHITE)),
    NOT_WHITE(Util.arrayListOf(Color.BLACK, Color.GRAY, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE));
    // and so on...
}
```

`Util.arrayListOf(T... values)` is basically just a wrapper around `new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(values))`.

One motivation of the `ColorListPreset` enum is syntactic sugar for, e.g., xml files. So, there are external forces at play here.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you posted your enums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to change `ColorListPreset` to some kind of a "builder" for a `Set<Color>` or `List<Color>`. It should not be an enum.

```
public class ColorListPreset {
    public static Set<Color> only(Color color) {
        return EnumSet.of(color);
    }

    public static Set<Color> not(Color color) {
        return EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(color));
    }

    // methods that return other color sets...
}
```

Usage example: For `ColorListPreset.NOT_WHITE`, you would write `ColorListPreset.not(Color.WHITE)`.

Comment: I guess method `not` would return `EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(color))`.

Comment: @MauricePerry Edited.

Comment: It sounds like a much better idea than generating (redundant) code.

Comment: I like using EnumSet, and complementOf, but I was hoping to not have to change the usage since there is a lot of inherited code. Though, that's more of an I-don't-want-to rather than an I-can't.

Comment: @Phlarx I feel like simple regexes could be used to change to this new usage.

Comment: @Sweeper That would work if this was all was self-contained. However, these enums are also referenced externally, such as in an xml file. I don't even know the full exent of these external forces, but I do know that a simple regex or two isn't quite enough. The path of least resistance with this route would include rewriting some of the parsing logic, methinks.